# VHDL Signal Declaration troubles?

Tags: vhdl, vivado

I cant figure out why vivado is throwing a syntax error on my signal declarations, anyone see something that I don't?
I have tried to move it around, but to no avail. Without it the only errors I get are those from trying to assign something from an output.

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity myip_v1_0 is
    generic (
        -- Users to add parameters here

        -- User parameters ends
        -- Do not modify the parameters beyond this line


        -- Parameters of Axi Slave Bus Interface S_AXIS
        C_S_AXIS_TDATA_WIDTH    : integer   := 32;

        -- Parameters of Axi Master Bus Interface M_AXIS
        C_M_AXIS_TDATA_WIDTH    : integer   := 32;
        C_M_AXIS_START_COUNT    : integer   := 32
    );
    port (
        -- Users to add ports here
        FRAME_SIZE : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
        EN          : in std_logic;
        AXI_EN      :IN STD_LOGIC;
        -- User ports ends
        -- Do not modify the ports beyond this line


        -- Ports of Axi Slave Bus Interface S_AXIS
        s_axis_aclk : in std_logic;
        s_axis_aresetn  : in std_logic;
        s_axis_tready   : out std_logic;
        s_axis_tdata    : in std_logic_vector(C_S_AXIS_TDATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        s_axis_tstrb    : in std_logic_vector((C_S_AXIS_TDATA_WIDTH/8)-1 downto 0);
        s_axis_tlast    : in std_logic;
        s_axis_tvalid   : in std_logic;

        -- Ports of Axi Master Bus Interface M_AXIS
        m_axis_aclk : in std_logic;
        m_axis_aresetn  : in std_logic;
        m_axis_tvalid   : out std_logic;
        m_axis_tdata    : out std_logic_vector(C_M_AXIS_TDATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        m_axis_tstrb    : out std_logic_vector((C_M_AXIS_TDATA_WIDTH/8)-1 downto 0);
        m_axis_tlast    : out std_logic;
        m_axis_tready   : in std_logic

    );


end myip_v1_0;

architecture arch_imp of myip_v1_0 is
    -- component declaration


    component myip_v1_0_S_AXIS is
        generic (
        C_S_AXIS_TDATA_WIDTH    : integer   := 32
        );
        port (
        S_AXIS_ACLK : in std_logic;
        S_AXIS_ARESETN  : in std_logic;
        S_AXIS_TREADY   : out std_logic;
        S_AXIS_TDATA    : in std_logic_vector(C_S_AXIS_TDATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        S_AXIS_TSTRB    : in std_logic_vector((C_S_AXIS_TDATA_WIDTH/8)-1 downto 0);
        S_AXIS_TLAST    : in std_logic;
        S_AXIS_TVALID   : in std_logic
        );
    end component myip_v1_0_S_AXIS;

    component myip_v1_0_M_AXIS is
        generic (
        C_M_AXIS_TDATA_WIDTH    : integer   := 32;
        C_M_START_COUNT : integer   := 32
        );
        port (
        M_AXIS_ACLK : in std_logic;
        M_AXIS_ARESETN  : in std_logic;
        M_AXIS_TVALID   : out std_logic;
        M_AXIS_TDATA    : out std_logic_vector(C_M_AXIS_TDATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
        M_AXIS_TSTRB    : out std_logic_vector((C_M_AXIS_TDATA_WIDTH/8)-1 downto 0);
        M_AXIS_TLAST    : out std_logic;
        M_AXIS_TREADY   : in std_logic
        );
    end component myip_v1_0_M_AXIS;
```

**how is this incorrect?**

```
    signal m_axis_tvalidw   : out std_logic_vector;
    signal m_axis_tdataw    : out std_logic_vector(C_M_AXIS_TDATA_WIDTH-1 downto 0);
    signal m_axis_tstrbw    : out std_logic_vector((C_M_AXIS_TDATA_WIDTH/8)-1 downto 0);
    signal m_axis_tlastw    : out std_logic;

begin

-- Instantiation of Axi Bus Interface S_AXIS
myip_v1_0_S_AXIS_inst : myip_v1_0_S_AXIS
    generic map (
        C_S_AXIS_TDATA_WIDTH    => C_S_AXIS_TDATA_WIDTH
    )
    port map (
        S_AXIS_ACLK => s_axis_aclk,
        S_AXIS_ARESETN  => s_axis_aresetn,
        S_AXIS_TREADY   => s_axis_tready,
        S_AXIS_TDATA    => s_axis_tdata,
        S_AXIS_TSTRB    => s_axis_tstrb,
        S_AXIS_TLAST    => s_axis_tlast,
        S_AXIS_TVALID   => s_axis_tvalid
    );

-- Instantiation of Axi Bus Interface M_AXIS
myip_v1_0_M_AXIS_inst : myip_v1_0_M_AXIS
    generic map (
        C_M_AXIS_TDATA_WIDTH    => C_M_AXIS_TDATA_WIDTH,
        C_M_START_COUNT => C_M_AXIS_START_COUNT
    )
    port map (
        M_AXIS_ACLK     => m_axis_aclk,
        M_AXIS_ARESETN  => m_axis_aresetn,
        M_AXIS_TVALID   => m_axis_tvalid,
        M_AXIS_TDATA    => m_axis_tdata,
        M_AXIS_TSTRB    => m_axis_tstrb,
        M_AXIS_TLAST    => m_axis_tlast,
        M_AXIS_TREADY   => m_axis_tready
    );
```

**without signals the else throw errors, since they are outputs.**

```
    -- Add user logic here
    --MULTIPLEXER
     m_axis_tdata <= S_AXIS_TDATA WHEN (AXI_EN='1') ELSE
     M_AXIS_TDATAW;

     m_axis_tSTRB <= S_AXIS_TSTRB WHEN (AXI_EN='1') ELSE
     M_AXIS_TSTRBW;

     m_axis_tLAST <= S_AXIS_TLAST WHEN (AXI_EN='1') ELSE
     M_AXIS_TLASTW;

     m_axis_TVALID <= S_AXIS_TVALID WHEN (AXI_EN='1') ELSE
     M_AXIS_TVALIDW;

    -- User logic ends

end arch_imp;
```

Comment: Please show the full error message.

Comment: `signal m_axis_tvalidw   : out std_logic_vector;` signals have no direction, you should remove the `out`. Also I think there needs to be a range constraint for a `std_logic_vector`, however in this case I think it is more likely that you actually meant `std_logic`.

Comment: After pasting your snippets into one design unit and applying the changes suggested by mkrieger  (removing reserved word `out` from signal declarations, changing the type for `m_axis_tvalidw` to std_logic) your code analyzes.

Answer (score 1):

Signals have no *mode* of e.g. `in`, `out` or `inout`.

All objects need to be fully constrained, but your signal `m_axis_tvalidw` is declared with an unconstrained type. You need to specify a range constraint.